# Copy multiple sheets at once (keeping relative formulas)

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I have been struggling for a while to find a way to copy multiple sheets at once using VBA. The catch is that i need them to keep their relative reference to each other. For example:

```
I have 3 sheets:
1. Print                      (formulas point to TV - Input)
2. Print - Input
3. Print - plan               (formulas point to TV - Input)

I need to copy them so that all formulas point to their new respective sheets.

1. Print (2)                  (formulas point to Print - Input (2))
2. Print - Input (2)
3. Print - plan (2)           (formulas point to Print - Input (2))
```

This is done easily by hand by Ctrl. + dragging the sheets to a new location. However how to i do this in VBA?

**Edit:**
The name "Print" is set runtime. So it can also be TV or Radio. It is pased from a string.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Sheets(Array("Print", "Print - input", "Print - plan")).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```

**Edited-** with index references

```
Sheets(Array(1, 2, 3)).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```

With variable references:

```
Dim sht1 as String, sht2 as String, sht3 As String
sht1 = "Print"
sht2 = "Print - input"
sht3 = "Print - plan"
Sheets(Array(sht1, sht2, sht3)).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```

With dynamic array (here 3 element static, but could be any dynamic one, too):

```
Dim arrSHT as Variant
arrSHT = array("Print", "Print - input", "Print - Plan")
Sheets(arrSHT).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! However this is part of a bigger function, and the sheet names are set dynamically. Is there a way to pass in a dynamic array variable or something?